# fetch resultset with one column as index and another as value in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a table with the following structure

```
+-------------+------+
| date        | price|
+-------------+------+
| 2014-02-19  |   34 |
| 2014-02-20  |   30 |
| 2014-02-21  |   28 |
+-------------+------+
```

If I use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC I can change an associative array in the following format,

```
array(
  0=> array(
    "date" =>  2014-02-19 ,
    "price" => 34
),
 1=> array(
    "date" =>  2014-02-20 ,
    "price" => 30
)

)
```

into this..

```
array(
"2014-02-19" => 34,
"2014-02-20" => 30,
"2014-02-21" => 28
)
```

using this chunk of code:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $results[$row['date']] = $row['price'];
}
```

I'm new to Yii, What would be the best way to achieve the same in Yii2, using Active Records. ( Or using `yii\db\query`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$models = YourModel::find()->all();
$results = ArrayHelper::map($models, 'date', 'price');
```

or you can loop the AR results like:

```
$results = [];
foreach($models as $model) {
    $results[$model->date] = $model->price;
}
```